# Autocorrect python library throwing error instead of correcting the word

Tags: python, python-3.x, autocorrect

I'm not really sure why this autocorrect isnt working, but every time i try to use the `Speller()` function i get this error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

and here is my code:

```
import time
from autocorrect import Speller

def main(consoleMode):
    if consoleMode:
        # beg fur input :D
        inputVar = input("Console Mode input: ")
        if Speller(inputVar.lower()) == "hi" or Speller(inputVar.lower()) == "hello" or Speller(inputVar.lower()) == "wassup" or Speller(inputVar.lower()) == "sup":
            if name == None:
                name = int(input("Hello!\nI'd like to get to know you.\nWhat's your name?\n> "))
                if ("not" in Speller(name) and "tell" in Speller(name)) or ("not" in Speller(name) and "say" in Speller(name)):
                    print("Alright, I'll just call you Bob for now :)")
                    name = "Bob"
            else:
                print("Hey " + name + "!")
while True:
    main(True)
```

edit: I also tried doing `int(disisastringvariable)` but it just doesnt even work as it also throws an error

Comment: Why are you making `name` an `int`?

Comment: @Nick i tried making it not an int and it still throws me the same error :\

Comment: Please include the *entire* error message, including the traceback.  Otherwise, we have to guess at the problem location.

Comment: @Prune Im running this on repl.it so heres the error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 17, in <module>
    main(True)
  File "main.py", line 8, in main
    if Speller(inputVar.lower()) == "hi" or Speller(inputVar.lower()) == "hello" or Speller(inputVar.lower()) == "wassup" or Speller(inputVar.lower()) == "sup":
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/autocorrect/__init__.py", line 27, in __init__
    if threshold > 0:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you might want to check out the documentation for the `autocorrect` module the `speller` class inits signature is `def __init__(self, threshold=0, lang='en'):` So when creating an instance of the class and passing in a single argument it will assume you are passing in a threshold.

So calling `Speller("something")` will pass a string in that will be stored as the threshold. then on line 27 of the init method. `if threshold > 0` this string will be compared to an int. Hence the error. Since you cannot do > between a string and an int.

I would suggest first read any documentation for this module. The example from the documenation suggest to use it like

```py
>>> spell = Speller(lang='en')
>>> spell("I'm not sleapy and tehre is no place I'm giong to.")
"I'm not sleepy and there is no place I'm going to."
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass the code you want to check to the `Speller` constructor.
Instead, you should create the object once, and then it is callable and checks input.  Read the examples here: https://github.com/fsondej/autocorrect

```
import time
from autocorrect import Speller

my_speller = Speller(lang='en')
name = None

def main(consoleMode):
    global name
    if consoleMode:
        # beg fur input :D
        inputVar = input("Console Mode input: ")
        if my_speller(inputVar.lower()) == "hi" or my_speller(inputVar.lower()) == "hello" or my_speller(inputVar.lower()) == "wassup" or my_speller(inputVar.lower()) == "sup":
            if name == None:
                name = input("Hello!\nI'd like to get to know you.\nWhat's your name?\n> ")
                if ("not" in my_speller(name) and "tell" in my_speller(name)) or ("not" in my_speller(name) and "say" in my_speller(name)):
                    print("Alright, I'll just call you Bob for now :)")
                    name = "Bob"
            else:
                print("Hey " + name + "!")

while True:
    main(True)
```

You also had a problem with the variable `name` being used before declaration - I think you want to have a global instance of this and use it in all calls to your main function.